# SVG filter feGaussianBlur and feColorMatrix not working in Safari/iOs, alternatives?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I see this code on a demo in codepen.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <filter id="goo">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="12" />
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
</svg>
```

It works fine in Chrome but not in Safari/iOs (I guess feGaussianBlur not working in safari, it doesn't has "gooey effect" look like Chrome or Firefox)

[`here is demo`](http://codepen.io/codecalm/pen/eppjjM)

How can i make it works  or js alternatives? Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add what do you mean by not working in safari. what was the expected result and what are you encountering?

Comment: I think feGaussianBlur not working in safari, it doesn't has "gooey effect" look like Chrome or Firefox, sorry! my bad English

Comment: Can confirm: still not working in Safari (macOS or iOS). Looking for a solution. Will post here if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

In this [page](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/#support) says:

> SVG filters have good support, but not all browsers support them being applied to regular DOM elements, notably Safari.

So use `<svg>` and `<circle>` elements instead of `<div>...</div>` in order to get better compatibility.

```css
html, body, div, svg {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
 @keyframes colors {
     0% {
         fill: #FBD301;
    }
     25% {
         fill: #FF3270;
    }
     50% {
         fill: #208BF1;
    }
     75% {
         fill: #AFE102;
    }
     100% {
         fill: #FBD301;
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-1 {
     20% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100px);
    }
     25% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-2 {
     25% {
         transform: none;
    }
     45% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(100px);
    }
     50% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(0);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-3 {
     50% {
         transform: none;
    }
     70% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(100px);
    }
     75% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-4 {
     75% {
         transform: none;
    }
     95% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-100px);
    }
     100% {
         transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(0);
    }
}
 circle {
     transform-origin: center;
     animation: colors ease 4s infinite;
}
 circle:nth-child(2) {
     animation: colors ease 4s infinite, rotate-1 ease 4s infinite;
}
 circle:nth-child(3) {
     animation: colors ease 4s infinite, rotate-2 ease 4s infinite;
}
 circle:nth-child(4) {
     animation: colors ease 4s infinite, rotate-3 ease 4s infinite;
}
 circle:nth-child(5) {
     animation: colors ease 4s infinite, rotate-4 ease 4s infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 0;position: absolute; pointer-events: none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="12" />
            <feColorMatrix values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div role="img" style="filter: url('#goo')">
    <svg>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: in safari iOS neither works sadly. safari just sucks..